# Related products are not visible in product page in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, related-products, product-view-page

I am facing an issue that related products are not visible in the product view page.

How can I show related products on the bottom section of the product view page?

Please help to find the solution.
Thanks

Comment: do u have added any related products in product catalog?

Comment: You must check your theme folder's catalog_product_view.xml has code for Related product block. If its there you can just assign related products from admin to the product you want to assign them. Path: app/design/frontend/yourtheme/custom/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: I have added related product which are in-stock and visible individually.

Comment: When I added the related product block, total related product alignment is missing and check box is not showing up. @Dinesh Rajput

Comment: share the screenshot for more detail.